# Webrtc SDP Audio is not working on sender side but receiver can listen sender voice

Tags: webrtc, sdp

Webrtc SDP Audio is not working on sender side but receiver can listen sender voice.
Video is working fine both side

Answer SDP:-

v=0\r\no=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-61.0 6227063584330165543 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 5B:EE:F9:8B:A4:77:24:AF:C8:1F:7A:12:75:1C:4B:6F:33:45:D9:3B:BB:05:F5:18:03:32:9D:2D:AB:BC:FC:01\r\na=group:BUNDLE sdparta_0 sdparta_1\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=msid-semantic:WMS *\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 101\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1\r\na=fmtp:101 0-15\r\na=ice-pwd:4c2cb9a31321054e816200974f041439\r\na=ice-ufrag:408ddefb\r\na=mid:sdparta_0\r\na=msid:{d83c16a6-8c6b-48a6-9df5-a0e26ca801f7} {f1388817-3547-4e77-aca1-da974eaa0dd3}\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000\r\na=setup:active\r\na=ssrc:711252568 cname:{83856f3b-3e35-4fff-8bd1-5c3a0a0b0cce}\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60\r\na=ice-pwd:4c2cb9a31321054e816200974f041439\r\na=ice-ufrag:408ddefb\r\na=mid:sdparta_1\r\na=msid:{d83c16a6-8c6b-48a6-9df5-a0e26ca801f7} {37ab4190-689d-4607-b031-5855790d6c10}\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000\r\na=setup:active\r\na=ssrc:984964499 cname:{83856f3b-3e35-4fff-8bd1-5c3a0a0b0cce}\r\n

Comment: Please format your code with new lines. Copy text in your local editor and make nice looking ... Please tell us about your host OS and which SIP server you are using? It is very interest because at the moment there is no working demo on the internet for all browsers . Special 'safari browser' if you have success with SDP tell us more...